# В чем отличие записи?

Tags: css

Какая разница между записями:

```
.logo, slogan {
    float: left;
}
```

и

```
 .logo, .slogan {
    float: left;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если точки нет, то это обращение к тегу (такому как <div>, <p>, <span> и т.д.) В вашем случай - селектор должен быть <slogan>

Если точка есть - это обращение к классу (<div class="slogan">, <p class="slogan">, <span class="slogan"> и т.д.)

Comment: Только не к селектору, а к тегу, потому что #id, .class, div - это все селекторы

Comment: Да, ошибся. поправил. спасибо.)

Answer (score 0):

В первом случае стили задаются для тега slogan, а во втором для класса slogan. Обращайте внимание на точки в css записях